# swift can't click uibutton located inside multiple subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I am not getting when I press the `arrowButton`, not even the `print("toggleWhiteMenu pressed")` is printing in the console? I have searched the other questions like this one but the don't seem to help.

```
 let card: UIView = {
        let tsl = UIView()
        tsl.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        tsl.alpha = 0.9
        return tsl
    }()


let yellowCard: UIView = {
    let tsl = UIView()
    tsl.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    //tsl.alpha = 1
     tsl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return tsl
}()



  lazy var arrowButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)

    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "down arrow"), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.black
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleWhiteMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()


func toggleWhiteMenu() {
    print("toggleWhiteMenu pressed")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

        self.whiteMenu.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 11, y: 11)
    }) { (true) in
        print("really sick")
    }
}


let whiteMenu: UIView = {
    let tsl = UIView()
    tsl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tsl.alpha = 1
    tsl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return tsl
}()



    let containerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()


let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "eiffel tower")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    return imageView
}()


func setUpViews() { 
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

        containerView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(card)
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(yellowCard)

        yellowCard.addSubview(whiteMenu)
        yellowCard.addSubview(arrowButton)

        ///i have left out constraints except for the arrowbutton's constraints as i don't deem them necessary for this question

        arrowButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width/6, height: view.frame.width/6)

        arrowButton.clipsToBounds = true

        arrowButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: whiteMenu.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        arrowButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: whiteMenu.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: one of our subview  may be overlapping UIButton  set different background colors for all subviews and check if your button is viewable if yes then check UIButton frame otherwise set subviews frame properly.

Comment: thanks  Abu Ul Hassan i did this and  the button is clearly on top of all subviews with no subview overlapping the button

Comment: Have you tried adding @objc in front of the toggleWhiteMenu func? It’s possible the compiler isn’t associating the func at run time because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Please add @objc with selector method like below.

```
 @objc func toggleWhiteMenu() {
    print("toggleWhiteMenu pressed")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

        self.whiteMenu.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 11, y: 11)
    }) { (true) in
        print("really sick")
    }
    }
```

Comment: add this line in end of your setUpViews
 arrowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleWhiteMenu), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: and remove it from lazy loading block.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting:

```
.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

on multiple views, and then adding a button as a subview. `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to **false** on a parent view will cascade down to all subviews, ***including*** buttons and other controls.